# Is there a free MS-Project Viewer?

Tags: software-rec, microsoft-project, viewer

What is the best free MS Project file (`.mpp`) viewer?

No editing needed, just the ability to see the list of tasks, the details of them (time, owner etc..) and the relationships between tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LiveProject Viewer](http://www.kadonk.com/) is free.
However it doesn't support printing or export (needs paid upgrade).

Comment: On the LiveProject web site, re: the free viewer:

"NOTE: LiveProject Free Viewer is limited to a maximum of 100 tasks per project and does not contain Premium features.

It is intended for personal, non-commercial use only. To try out the full version or for commercial/evaluation purposes, download LiveProject Premium Viewer or Collaboration instead."

Answer (score 5):

[MOOS Project Viewer](http://www.moosprojectviewer.com/) has the ability to view any type of MS Project files (mpp, mpt, mpx, xml). I've not tried it yet

Comment: It currently has a 30-day trial. Not free.

Comment: Hey, found the free version, download it here: http://www.free-project-viewer.com

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give ["OpenProj - Project Management"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openproj/files/) a try. It claims to open MSProject files.

Alternatively, you may export the schedule from MS project (if you have one) in HTML format and send it to others who only want to view it.

Comment: I think you can export to Excel as well.

Comment: Very buggy, at least on the Mac.

Comment: The development seems to have stopped... Looks like a dead project.